# viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear not being called, not firing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, viewwillappear

(This is both question and answer since it took quite a bit of digging to find the real answer.)

Symptom: `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` were not being called in my UIViewController.

Cause: Embedding a `UINavigationController` or `UITabBarController` (my case) in a `UIViewController` somehow interrupts with the calling of these methods.

Solution: Call them manually in the `UIViewController` that contains the aforementioned `UINavigationController` / `UITabBarController`.

For example (assuming `projectNavigationController` is your `UINavigationController`):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [projectNavigationController viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [projectNavigationController viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [projectNavigationController viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [projectNavigationController viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

In my case I had an inner `UITabBarController` and I called the methods accordingly and all was solved.

(Attribution on the solution: http://davidebenini.it/2009/01/03/viewwillappear-not-being-called-inside-a-uinavigationcontroller/)

Comment: just because I'm curious...: why would you wrap a tab bar controller into another viewcontroller? :) in most cases, they are the root of the view (controller) hierarchy...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and disagree with @St3fan, and use `UIKit` as the counter-example.

***However, the wisdom (or lack thereof), of embedding controllers in general should be guided by sane UI design principles.***

The easiest counter-example is `UINavigationControllers` embedded in `UITabBarControllers`.  These appear all over the place.  Just off the top of my head, the iPod app on iPhone, and Contacts within the Phone app on iPhone.

I was curious enough to bother to check what they do with the views (add to the "super-controller" view or to the `UIWindow`. I was pretty sure I was going to find that the sub-controller views were descendants of the super-controller views in the view hierarchy, which is contrary to St3fan's recommendation.

I whipped up a very quick iPhone app hooking everything up in InterfaceBuilder to create a `UITabBarController` based app with two tabs, the first of which was a `UINavigationController` with a plain ole `UIViewController` as it's root view controller, and a 2nd tab with a plain old `UIViewController` just so I had a 2nd tab to click later.

Sprinkle in some `NSLog` statements to output the various `UIView's` for the controllers we see this:

```
tabBarController.view = <UILayoutContainerView: 0x5b0dc80; ...
navigationController.view = <UILayoutContainerView: 0x59469a0; ...
rootViewController.view = <UIView: 0x594bb70; ...
Superview: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x594cc90; ...
Superview: <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x594a420; ...
Superview: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x59469a0; ... // navigationController.view
Superview: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x594b430; ...
Superview: <UITransitionView: 0x5b0e110; ...
Superview: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x5b0dc80; ... // tabBarController.view
Superview: <UIWindow: 0x5942a30; ...
```

The lines prefixed with "Superview" were the output from walking up the `rootViewController.view's` superview chain until hitting nil.

Then of course a quick glance at the call stack in a couple of places where `viewDidDisappear` would get called on the root view controller.

First, the call stack when `viewDidDisappear` is called on the root controller as a result of a new controller being pushed on to the stack:

```
-[RootController viewDidDisappear:]
-[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:]
...
```

Second, the call stack when another tab is selected in the top-most UITabBarController:

```
-[RootController viewDidDisappear:]
-[UINavigationController viewDidDisappear:]
-[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:]
```

So in all cases, it seems that Apple decided that controllers should be calling the various `viewDidAppear`, etc methods on their embedded subcontrollers and that the view's should be embedded similarly.  I think the OP hit this nail right on the head if we're to take `UIKit` design as a good lead to follow.

Comment: Interesting analysis imaginaryboy. I appreciate your POV St3fan.

In typical setups, the UITabBarController (which has it's own navigation controllers and view controllers) is added to the window. It's very easy to see this.

However, my situation was slightly different. In my case the user enters a specific mode of the application via a modal. In this other mode, there is a different UITabBarController from the one the user sees originally. Perhaps I could've called the app delegate to add the new UITabBarcontroller to the window (?) but adding it to the modal UIViewController was easier.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this same circumstance.  Earlier the interface builder segue triggered by a table cell selection had stopped working and after some exasperation digging into the code, I just set it up manually, calling from the cell-selection override in the table view delegate.

Later I made some layout changes in the called view controller and saw that viewDidAppear wasn't being called, as described above.  The debug output made reference to "nested push operations" or something, and since I had a big comment to myself in my manual push operation

`#warning I SHOULD NOT HAVE TO DO THIS!!`

I breakpointed the segue code and, sure enough, the IB segue was now working, and it was my manual operation in the table cell selection code that was messing up the delegate calls in the called view.  I removed the manual code and everything is fine again.

It does seem odd that the cell select code gets called after the view is pushed.  I have to do a protocol and delegate to get the indexpath of the selected cell in the caller.