# Auto Layout constraint on CALayer IOS

Tags: ios, autolayout, calayer

Hi I am developing iPhone application in which I tried to set one side border for edittext. I did this in following way:

```
 int borderWidth = 1;
CALayer *leftBorder = [CALayer layer];

leftBorder.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
leftBorder.borderWidth = borderWidth;

leftBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, textField
                              .frame.size.width, borderWidth);
[textField.layer addSublayer:leftBorder];
```

I put some constraints on my edittext in IB so that when I rotate my device it will adjust width of text field according to that. My problem is that adjusts the width of edittext not adjusting the width of CALayer which I set for my edit text. So I think I have to put some constraints for my CALayer item as well. But I dont know how to do that. ANy one knows about this? Need Help. Thank you.

Comment: not possible. Constraints only work with UIView

Answer (score 131):

the whole autoresizing business is view-specific. layers don't autoresize.

what you have to do -- in code -- is to resize the layer yourself

e.g.

in a viewController you would do

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
  [super viewDidLayoutSubviews]; //if you want superclass's behaviour... 
  // resize your layers based on the view's new frame
  self.editViewBorderLayer.frame = self.editView.bounds;
}
```

or in a custom UIView you could use

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews]; //if you want superclass's behaviour...  (and lay outing of children)
  // resize your layers based on the view's new frame
  layer.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

Comment: If you are using layoutSubviews you should call it on super

Comment: @rmp251 neither docs nor header files say so and it seems weird. i mean I would only retain the default behaviour -- auto layout (on ios51+).. might be what one wants but it isn't always right ... so no AFAIK

Comment: This solution doesn't work if the view that owns the layer is sized via autolayout constraints. In this case the bounds and frame properties don't reflect the actual bounds/frame as determined by the constraints. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlfieHanssen you mean if it is the view's backing layer? no then of course not as the view and the layer are basically one.

Comment: @AlfieHanssen they do reflect the actual frame and bounds. LayoutSubviews does that. You can also fire after ViewDidAppear. Also calling layoutIfNeeded, InvalidateIntrinsic, etc...

Comment: @AlfieHanssen updating the frame in viewDidAppear worked for me as suggested Nick Turner.

Comment: This also doesn't work when you are animating autolayout constraints with layoutIfNeeded on a view which has some sublayers that should reflect the view's frame..

Answer (score 14):

In `Swift 5`, you can try the following solution:

Use KVO, for the path "YourView.bounds" as given below.

```
self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "YourView.bounds", options: .new, context: nil)
```

Then handle it as given below.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "YourView.bounds" {
            YourLayer.frame = YourView.bounds
            return
        }
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
```

More info about this [here](https://marcosantadev.com/calayer-auto-layout-swift/)

Comment: This worked superbly and I think is the best approach to take with "autolayout" as opposed to doing it in *layoutsubviews

Comment: The URL in the answer is broken.

Comment: URL is still broken

Comment: Not sure what is the issue. The ref url still works for me. https://www.marcosantadev.com/calayer-auto-layout-swift/

Answer (score 9):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5330162/934710) answer, `layoutSubviews` does not get called in all needed cases. I have found this delegate method more effective:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self != nil) {
        [self.layer addSublayer:self.mySublayer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
    self.mySublayer.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

My solution when I create with dashed border

```
class DashedBorderView: UIView {

   let dashedBorder = CAShapeLayer()

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       commonInit()
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       commonInit()
   }

   private func commonInit() {
       //custom initialization
       dashedBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
       dashedBorder.lineDashPattern = [2, 2]
       dashedBorder.frame = self.bounds
       dashedBorder.fillColor = nil
       dashedBorder.cornerRadius = 2
       dashedBorder.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
       self.layer.addSublayer(dashedBorder)
   }

   override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
       super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
       dashedBorder.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
       dashedBorder.frame = self.bounds
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.x KVO Solution**
(Updated @arango_86's answer)

**Add Observer**

```
self.addObserver(
    self, 
    forKeyPath: "<YOUR_VIEW>.bounds", 
    options: .new, 
    context: nil
)
```

**Observe Values**

```
override open func observeValue(
    forKeyPath keyPath: String?, 
    of object: Any?, 
    change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, 
    context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
) {
    if (keyPath == "<YOUR_VIEW.bounds") {
      updateDashedShapeLayerFrame()
      return
    }

    super.observeValue(
        forKeyPath: keyPath, 
        of: object, 
        change: change, 
        context: context
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I have to apply KVO I prefer to do it with RxSwift (Only if I am using it for more stuff, do not add this library just for this.)

You can apply KVO with this library too, or in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but I've had better results with this.

```
  view.rx.observe(CGRect.self, #keyPath(UIView.bounds))
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
            guard let bounds = $0 else { return }
            self?.YourLayer.frame = bounds
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

Riffing off [arango_86's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41868339/8653957) – if you are applying the KVO fix within your own UIView subclass, the more "Swifty" way to do this is to override `bounds` and use `didSet` on it, like so:

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        layer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem - needing to set the frame of a 'CALayer' when using auto layout with views (in code, not *IB*).

In my case, I had a slightly convoluted hierarchy, having a view controller within a view controller. I ended up at this SO question and looked into the approach of using `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. That didn't work. Just in case your situation is similar to my own, here's what I found...

**Overview**

I wanted to set the frame for the `CAGradientLayer` of a `UIView` that I was positioning as a subview within a `UIViewController` using auto layout constraints.

Call the subview `gradientView` and the view controller `child_viewController`.

`child_viewController` was a view controller I'd set up as a kind of re-usable component. So, the `view` of `child_viewController` was being composed into a parent view controller - call that `parent_viewController`.

When `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of `child_viewController` was called, the `frame` of `gradientView` was not yet set.

(At this point, I'd recommend sprinkling some `NSLog` statements around to get a feel for the sequence of creation of views in your hierarchy, etc.)

So I moved on to try using `viewDidAppear`. However, due to the nested nature of `child_viewController` I found  `viewDidAppear` was not being called.

(See this SO question: [viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear not being called, not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560669/viewwillappear-viewdidappear-not-being-called-not-firing)).

**My current solution**

I've added `viewDidAppear` in `parent_viewController` and from there I'm calling `viewDidAppear` in `child_viewController`.

For the initial load I need `viewDidAppear` as it's not until this is called in `child_viewController` that all of the subviews have their frames set. I can then set the frame for the `CAGradientLayer`...

I've said that this is my *current solution* because I'm not particularly happy with it.

After initially setting the frame of the `CAGradientLayer` - that frame can become invalid if the layout changes - e.g. rotating the device.

To handle this I'm using `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in `child_viewController` - to keep the frame of the `CAGradientLayer` within `gradientView`, correct.

It works but doesn't feel good.
(Is there a better way?)

Comment: Generally you should not call view appearance/lifecycle methods manually. Daij-Djan has the right idea in this particular case.