# Gradient Layer Not Filling View

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a gradient layer that isn't filling the view it's assigned to. The constraints on view are top, left, right 0 and bottom 8. Below will be the code of the gradient and an image of the issue. The buttons are also inside the view so you can see that it is in fact filling the width of the screen.
I greatly appreciate any help on this. It's making absolutely no sense to me.

Here's the code:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
let picker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setup gradient
    gradientLayer.frame = self.gradientBackground.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [Constants.Colors.brightOrange.cgColor, Constants.Colors.lightOrange.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0,1.0]
    self.gradientBackground.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

[image: Here's the image:]

Comment: Could you check that `self.gradientBackground.bounds` isn't correct when you try to create your layer in `viewDidLoad()`? If that's the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303279/auto-layout-constraint-on-calayer-ios

Comment: The bounds are correct :/

Comment: Could you move that code in layoutSubview or viewDidAppear?

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews() did it!

Comment: So, my guess, is that when I asked about the value of the `bounds`, and you said it was correct, what I meant, is in viewDidAppear/viewDidLayoutSubviews/viewDidLoad, may not have the same value for the bounds.

Comment: How do I give a comment credit for answering the question? Or do you need to make an actual answer?

Comment: Leo Dabus found a great duplicate question with good answer/explaination. Upvote there ;)

Comment: Swift Gradient View sample http://stackoverflow.com/a/37243106/2303865